# SQLite Order By Date1530019888000

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-order-by

Every record in my `SQLite` database contains a field which contains a `Date` stored as a `string` in the format `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'`.

Is it possible to query the database to get the record which contains the most recent date please?

Comment: You should store the date in milliseconds and convert every time you need to display it. This will then make it easier when sorting etc.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY date(dateColumn) DESC Limit 1
```

Comment: note that if you want to order by date **and time** you need to use `datetime()` intead of `date()`

Comment: what if date string is in format "dd-mm-yyyy"? for this ur answer is not working

Comment: This answered confused me. for me no need to use the "date" or "datetime" function around the date field name. check Nabi K.A.Z. answer

Answer (score 48):

For me I had my query this way to solve my problem

```
select *  from Table order  by datetime(datetimeColumn) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Since I was storing it as datetime not date column

Comment: Additionally,The date() function returns the date in this format: YYYY-MM-DD. The time() function returns the time as HH:MM:SS. The datetime() function returns "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".

Comment: What difference you made with your answer than previous one?@Ahmad Baraka

Comment: yes. This is working. Thanks.  I set my date to format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss and datetime(datetimeColumn)

Comment: What is LIMIT 1 Do?

Answer (score 12):

When you sure the format of text field is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` (ex.: `2017-01-02 16:02:55`), So It works for me simply:

`SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY dateColumn DESC Limit 1`

Without any extra date function!

Comment: yes. This is working. Thanks.  I set my date to format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss and datetime(datetimeColumn)

Answer (score 6):

You need to convert it to unix timestamp, and then compare them:

```
SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY strftime('%s', date_column) DESC
```

But this can be pretty slow, if there are lots of rows.
Better approach would be to store unix timestamp by default, and create an index for that column.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert your column `sent_date_time` to `yyyy-MM-dd` format and then order by date:

```
1) substr(sent_date_time,7,4)||"-"||substr(sent_date_time,1,2)||"-"||substr(sent_date_time,4,2) as date
2) order by date desc
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case everything works fine **without** **casting** column to type 'date'. Just by specifying column name with **double** quotes like that:

```
SELECT * FROM 'Repair' ORDER BY "Date" DESC;
```

I think SQLite makes casting by itself or something like that, but when I tried to 'cast' Date column by myself it's not worked. And there was no error messages.

Comment: This is not working if I think Sqlite uses the date/time the cell data were added , when I change one cell `Dat` column it's still sort it after newer date like this  https://i.ibb.co/Qv1zKQC/sqlitedatetime.png

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following query

```
"SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'," + dateColumn + ") DESC  Limit 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this ugly hack worked.

select *, substr(date_col_name,7,4)as yy,
substr(date_col_name,4,2) as mm,
substr(date_col_name,1,2) as dd
from my_table
order by yy desc,mm desc,dd desc

it would be better to convert the text column to date field type, but I found that did not work reliably for me.

Comment: This is the only solution worked for me lol ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you do a lot of date sorting/comparison, you may get better results by storing time as ticks rather than strings, here is showing how to get 'now' in ticks with:

```
((strftime('%s', 'now') - strftime('%S', 'now') + strftime('%f', 'now')) * 1000)
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20478329/460084)

Then it's easy to sort, compare, etc ...

Comment: 1) The OP has a SARGable value, so the conversion wouldn't be necessary.  2) You're converting `NOW` instead of the stored value, so that's not terribly helpful... 3) There appear to be better conversions (like the accepted answer), negating the need for the manual conversion.  What benefit does your answer provide over any of the others?

Comment: 1) SARG ? not sure what that is .. 2) 'now' was just an example, updated my answer, 3) accepted answer will convert string to int before every comparison which is very inefficient and I think will not work for sorted indexes

Answer (score 0):

This will work for both date and time

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
ORDER BY 
julianday(dateColumn) 
DESC Limit 1
```