# Web sql dates ordered as text and not by date precedence

Tags: html, web-services, web-sql

I am consuming an Oracle APEX REST web service  using HTML5. Some records are retrived from the server and stored locally using **web sql**. Local table has the same structure as the server db table, including a DATETIME column.

```
Example data:
01   10-03-2015 12:00  (March 10th, 2015)
02   01-04-2015 13:45  (April first, 2015)
03   03-05-2015 20:00  (May 3rd, 2015)
```

I have trouble with local storage (web sql) because when I order all table records by that datetime column, it is ordering the records following a text based order (from left to right): **DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI**

The code I am using in HTML5 to get these records ordered is:

```
select * 
from local_table
order by fecha
```

Wrongly I am getting this:

```
02   01-04-2015 13:45  (April first, 2015)
03   03-05-2015 20:00  (May 3rd, 2015)
01   10-03-2015 12:00  (March 10th, 2015)
```

When you check this records directly in Oracle DB without specifying a format, DATES are stored **DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI**. Oracle is not having trouble ordering those records by DATE because when I order them in ORACLE i am getting the right order:

```
01   10-03-2015 12:00  (March 10th, 2015)
02   01-04-2015 13:45  (April first, 2015)
03   03-05-2015 20:00  (May 3rd, 2015)
```

Do I have to order date value just before I store it locally in order to have it stored in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI so I can have them correctly ordered?

I saw another post where somebody suggest that, but I wonder if that is a workaround or the only way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WebSQL uses SQLite under the hood, so your question is answered here: 
[SQLite Order By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091183/sqlite-order-by-date)

You basically need to convert column values with date() function when ordering.