# How do I fetch a particular record based on Last Week, The current week using datetime() function?

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a SQLite DB table which contains Date & time for each item. How do I fetch those records which belongs to current week and which are of the previous week. I tried doing it with `datetime()` function but could not find a better solution/approach.

I'm trying this for a `XAMARIN` form based application.

Please do let me know how this can be achived.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: getdate() gets you current day. dateadd(day, -7, getdate()) gets you exactly 1 week prior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite Order By Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091183/sqlite-order-by-date)

Comment: is  it only a date or datetime?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible

**Update :**
Only Last week (excluding the current week)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d',ItemDate ) >= date('now','-14 days') AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d',ItemDate )<=date('now','-7 days')
```

Current week

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(ItemDate ) >= DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days');
```

Comment: Thanks.. For current week can I use something like this?,   '            SELECT* FROM table WHERE ItemDate >= datetime('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days');
'

Comment: SQLite don't support date/datetime storage: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#section_2_2

Comment: @jzeferino:  Since there is no support for storing date in `sqlite`, I'm storing it as `varchar()`.. Now how do I fetch the dates? can I use those above mentioned approaches?

Comment: There are already answers for this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091183/sqlite-order-by-date and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975737/sqlite-datetime-comparison hope it helps.

Comment: @VinayakGH updated the answer, now u will get the last week excluding the current week

Comment: @Balaji: Since there is nno support to store date in sqlite, I'm storing the same in string format and converting back to DATE before executing the query.Is that right?

Comment: @VinayakGH yes, here's that date which i'm using is `ItemDate`. Dont get confused, updated it.. is this fine?

Answer (score 0):

Use the date() function in your where clause.  This example I'm starting at now and getting the last days of the week `date('now', 'weekday 6')` and then starting now, getting the first day of next week, and -2 weeks `date('now', 'weekday 0', '-14 day')`

```
 select field1, field2 from table where 
 datefield < date('now', 'weekday 6') and datefield > date('now', 'weekday 0', '-14 day')
```