# Sorting a table by Date SQlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I  have a table with 3 columns.(Id-Primary Key, Task-string, due date-string). i want to insert task and set due date. Then, i want to display them in list view.Before i display them in list view, i want this table sorted based on date from most recent to least.

Comment: `I know how to sort just a column, but i want to sort entire table` what does this mean? Simply retrieve the whole table and sort it on the date column.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14091321/2620080

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite Order By Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091183/sqlite-order-by-date)

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASEHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,
result_columns, where,
whereArgs, groupBy, having, order);
```

so argument order will be "COLUMN_NAME ASC"