# Fetching data from sqlite database based on timestamp of present day

Tags: android, sqlite

In my android sqlite database there is a column that contains the timestamp in the format (2013-12-12 18:47:31) of the data. Now a  particular data may have time stamp which is earlier than present day or later than present day. e.g. today its 20 December 2013, and database contains data of 1 November 2013, 6 November 2013, 12 December 2013, 1 January 2014 etc... Now I want to fetch data which are earlier than present day i.e. 20 December 2013. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select [Columns] from [database] where [column_date] < "currentDate";
```

To get current date and time, check this link [Get current time and date on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/android-get-current-time-and-date)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following query to fetch the data based on timestamp

```
SELECT [COLUMN 1], [COLUMN 2]...., [COLUMN N] FROM [TABLE] WHERE TIMESTAMP_FIELD < strftime('%s','now');
```

[- Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Else you can also fetch currentTimeStamp like this

```
SELECT [COLUMN 1], [COLUMN 2]...., [COLUMN N] FROM [TABLE] WHERE TIMESTAMP_FIELD <
CAST((((JulianDay('now', 'localtime') - 2440587.5)*86400.0) + 62135596800) * 10000000
AS BIGINT)
```

[- Link for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5969409/1160282)

Answer (score 1):

`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` datetime stamps have the same lexicographical and chronological order. You can use operators such as `<` and `>` on the strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
Time time = new Time();

time.setToNow();
```

**OR**

```
Date todayDate = new Date();

todayDate.getDay();

todayDate.getHours();

todayDate.getMinutes();

todayDate.getMonth();

todayDate.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem of fetching data using timestamps but to no avail after weeks i got a good solution.

1. set column timestamp as text on your table

```
 public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                    + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                    + COLUMN_INCOME + " INTEGER,"
                    + COLUMN_EXPENSE + " INTEGER,"
                    + COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " TEXT"
                    + ")";
```

2. get the date using new Date() and convert to string

```
 private String getDateTime() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
```

3. Insert data in your table using the getDateTime() for the timestamp

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(DailyTransaction.COLUMN_INCOME, income);
        values.put(DailyTransaction.COLUMN_EXPENSE, expense);
        values.put(DailyTransaction.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP, getDateTime());
```

4. Then your sqlite query will look like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + ClassName.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " <"+ "'"currentDate'";
```