# DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds vs sqlite strftime

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

My Sqlite database has a 'Time' field of type 'INTEGER'

I write Unix time (epoch) to it from a C++ windows service like this:

`insert into ServicesData (Time, ...) values (((strftime('%s', 'now') - strftime('%S', 'now') + strftime('%f', 'now')) * 1000), ...);`

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20478329/460084 "grabbing the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (%s), subtracting the number of seconds in the current time (%S), adding the number of seconds with decimal places (%f), and multiplying the result by 1000 to convert from seconds to milliseconds")

I then read the date from a .NET Core 3.1 console app like this:

```
public class ServicesData {
  [Key]
  public long Time { get; set; }
  ... 
  public string ToString() {
    string res="";
    var time = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(Time).DateTime;
    res+= time.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss") + " ";
    ... return res;
  }
}
```

I now do a query from my .NET app *on the same box* and verify that the integer value of `ServicesData.Time` is the same as that on the database using DB Browser for SQLite

However on calling `ToString()` the resultant displayed date is *one hour* FW of the time when the entry was written to the DB !

Why aren't the dates matching ?

(note I tried replacing `FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(Time).DateTime` with `FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(Time).UtcDateTime;` but got the same result)

Comment: current culture difference?

Comment: possibly or day light saving but I can't see how/where is that set ? or how to fix it ?

Comment: i would take a look at the machine settings you are running the code on to get that identified to start with in terms of date-time settings

Comment: all code both writing and reading are on the same machine, that is why I am confused

Comment: It would be a *LOT* easier for everyone (including you a few days later) if you stored ISO dates. SQLite doesn't prefer ISO dates over Unix timestamps, nor are they more accurate. In fact, the Unix timestamp is per *second* and so has lower precision that the ISO string that goes into milliseconds

Comment: In any case, `FromUnixTimeMilliseconds` assumes UTC. If the C++ code stored *local* time when DST rules were in effect, there will be a 1 hour difference and there's nothing that can be done. The data was stored in the wrong way to begin with.

Comment: If you're in the UK, 1970 was permanently on DST, so 1-1-1970 was UTC+1. That's enough to mangle the timestamp calculation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are probably right, though storing strings is much less efficient ... I did get it to work in the end see below but still not sure why `FromUnixTimeMilliseconds` wan't working

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why `FromUnixTimeMilliseconds` above doesn't work, but this works correctly:

```
var time = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
  .AddMilliseconds(Time)
  .ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: That's equivalent to `FromUnixTimeMilliseconds (Time).ToLocalTime()`. It's the addition of `ToLocalTime()` at the end that makes the difference - but I would personally be pretty nervous about doing that. Do you *really* want the server-local version of that timestamp?

Comment: That doesn't really mean it's the right thing to do. For example, you might read it on that machine, but then return it as a local time to a user - at which point, the local time is pointless. And what happens if later you move the server? I would advise you to think *very* carefully about how you want to handle time zones.

Comment: Thanks Jon will do, also do you have any other clues/solutions to the issue?

Comment: Not really, because you haven't described clearly exactly what you're trying to achieve. It looks like you're probably correctly storing a UTC timestamp (although I'm not 100% certain of that) - you then need to think about what you want to do with that afterwards.